# How to remove .. from given path

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a path of `../hello/world/foo.txt`, or `../..hello/world/bar.txt`, how do I safely return `hello/world/foo.txt` or `hello/world/bar.txt` with Python?

I would simply like to rid of any prefixed relative path references

```
../hello/world/foo.txt      => hello/world/foo.txt
../../hello/world/bar.txt   => hello/world/bar.txt
./hello/world/boo.txt       => hello/world/boo.txt
hello/world/moo.txt         => hello/world/moo.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to be as portable as possible.

- using `os.normpath` first
- then split according to `os.sep` (slash/antislash)
- then filter out path parts which are *exactly* current or parent dir

like this:

```
import os

strings = """../hello/world/foo.txt
../../hello/world/bar.txt
./hello/world/boo.txt
hello/world/moo.txt
hello/world./moo.txt
"""

for p in strings.splitlines():
    print(os.sep.join([x for x in os.path.normpath(p).split(os.sep) if x not in (os.pardir,os.curdir)]))
```

result (on windows):

```
hello\world\foo.txt
hello\world\bar.txt
hello\world\boo.txt
hello\world\moo.txt
hello\world.\moo.txt
```

replace `os.sep.join` by `"/".join` to force slashes on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
s = '../../hello/world/bar.txt'
>>> "/".join(i for i in s.split('/') if '.' not in i[0])
'hello/world/bar.txt'
```

You can use `os.path.join` like this,

```
>>> os.path.join(*[i for i in s.split('/') if '.' not in i[0]])
'hello\\world\\bar.txt'
```

Comment: Is there a safer method using os.path rather than string manipulation?

Comment: @jchi2241 There's `pathlib` in stdlib

Comment: @jchi2241 Answer was updated. Is that what you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this simple regex :
`.` denotes current directory
`..` denotes directory just above the current directory.

Hence, only `.` and `..` will be present in the path. So, dot `.` has either 1 or 2 occurrences in the path followed by a `/`. Regex will be -> `r'\.{1,2}/'`

```
>>> string = "../../hello/world/bar.txt"
>>> result = re.sub(r'\.{1,2}/','',string)
>>> print(result)
hello/world/bar.txt

>>> string = ".././hello/world/bar.txt"
>>> result = re.sub(r'\.{1,2}/','',string)
>>> print(result)
hello/world/bar.txt

>>> string = "./hello/world/bar.txt"
>>> result = re.sub(r'\.{1,2}/','',string)
>>> print(result)
hello/world/bar.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

your can use  `path.split('..')[-1].strip('.').strip('/')`

Comment: `.strip('.').strip('/')` => `.strip('./')`

Comment: yes. but by separating, it can remove '/' at the start for the following text  `../hello/world/foo.txt` after splitting with '..'

Comment: it works with multiple chars too. Try it. `strip` treats each char individually